# How do I automatically restart my python code after it exits on an error?

Tags: python

The following doesn't work. I have a program that connects to a web page, but sometimes due to some problems it can't connect I want the program to completely restart after the error all by it self. Imagine the main function calls the program, how can I write such a code?

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    np.load('File.csv')

for i in range(1, 10):
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print 'Restarting!'
        main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it inside python use `try/except` accordingly:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    np.load('File.csv')

for i in range(1, 10):
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print 'Restarting!'
        continue
    else:
        break
```

For simple instructions this works, but if your code gets more complex, putting your whole `main()` function into a `try/except` block can hide exceptions and can make your program hard to debug. Thus I would recommend to handle the restart outside python e.g. in a bash script.

Answer (score 3):

you can very well use recursive function here to restart your code automatically. use setrecursionlimit() to define number of attempts as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10)  # set recursion depth limit


def main():
    try:
        a = np.load('file.csv')
        if a:
            return a
    except Exception as e:
        return main()

result = main()
print result
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

For something like this (connecting to a web page), it's often better to make the upper limit based on time instead of the number of times you attempt to connect. So use a `while` loop instead:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def main():
    np.load('file.csv')

start = time.time()
stop = start + 5
attempts = 0
result = 'failed'

while True:
    if time.time()<stop:
        try:
            main()
        except Exception as e:
            attempts += 1
            print e
            time.sleep(0.1) # optional
            print 'Restarting!'
            continue
        else:
            result = 'succeeded'
    print 'Connection %s after %i attempts.' % (result, attempts)
    break
```

Optional: I included a 100 ms pause after each failed attempt. This can help with establishing a connection sometimes.

Then wrap the whole thing up in a function you can use in the future for other projects:

```
# retry.py

import time

def retry(f, seconds, pause = 0):
    start = time.time()
    stop = start + seconds
    attempts = 0
    result = 'failed'

    while True:
        if time.time()<stop:
            try:
                f()
            except Exception as e:
                attempts += 1
                print e
                time.sleep(pause)
                print 'Restarting!'
                continue
            else:
                result = 'succeeded'
        print '%s after %i attempts.' % (result, attempts)
        break
```

now just do this:

```
import numpy as np
from retry import retry

def main():
    np.load('file.csv')

retry(main, 5, 0.1)
```

Testing procedure:

```
class RetryTest():
    def __init__(self, succeed_on = 0, excp = Exception()):
        self.succeed_on = succeed_on
        self.attempts = 0
        self.excp = excp
    def __call__(self):
        self.attempts += 1
        if self.succeed_on == self.attempts:
            self.attempts = 0
        else:
            raise self.excp

retry_test1 = RetryTest(3)
retry(retry_test1, 5, 0.1)
# succeeded after 3 attempts.
retry_test2 = RetryTest()
retry(retry_test2, 5, 0.1)
# failed after 50 attempts.
```

Comment: @auryndb it was actually a little bit broken earlier; fixed now.